# How to use material-ui dialog in scheduler?

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui, scheduler

I am currenlty [react-big-scheduler](https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler/blob/master/example/ResourceClickable.js) to create my application. However, I am facing a problem replacing with my material-ui dialog.

```
newEvent = (...) => {
    if(window.confirm('...'){
    ...
    }
```

When I export material-ui dialog as a component and replaced the code to:

```
newEvent = (...) => {
    <NewEventDialog />
}
```

I have the following error:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

As I am new to react, my questions would be:

- I am intending to replace the window.confirm to a more visually appealing one such as material-ui
- How would you suggest I import it into my current scheduler?
- How do I pass on the "submit" boolean to my scheduler?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to return the from the `newEvent` Component

```
newEvent = (...) => {
  return (<NewEventDialog />)
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to return it the dialog component. I am using this from material-ui (https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/#form-dialogs). i import it as a component and did as above but the dialog still doesnt open. I wrote the return statement in the first line inside newEvent.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue too. Bump!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/k14rp64q87

hello, this is the code i currently have now. my scheduler is inside src/components/Schedule/Scheduler.js

Comment: Referencing from your codesandbox, in Scheduler.js i added in 
- Line 61 to 63
- Line 69 to 71 

in BookingDialog.js i changed Line 32 and Line 35.

Am i missing anything? Im am still getting an error "Unable to find node on an unmounted component" pointing to the this.setState in newEvent. 

Thank you so much for your help though!! So sorry still encountering a problem :(